# Two UIStackviews that expand to full width of view?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to create a UI that looks like [image: this]

Each ImageView and Team Label is inside a Vertical Stack View (since some teams do not have logos, I will hide the imageViews and let the Team name center itself inside the stackView)

However, when I try to add leading and trailing constraints to my stackviews (the VS label should be centered in the parentview) this is what happens, even though I have constrained the parent view to its superview...:

[image]

I've also lowered the content hugging priority of my stackviews but they still hug their contents. I can only achieve the UI I want by using >= constraints for my leading or trailing, as seen here:

[image]

But this does not let the stackviews expand horizontally to the available width (so the team name can fit)

Does anyone know how to make my stackviews get the available with? My "VS" view has a fixed width constraint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a visual bug in Xcode (compressing the views to their content size), and when running my second screenshot's layout on an actual device, the layout works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Create Dark Gray view as `UIStackView`. Inside stack put three `UIView`. Make `UIStackView` as "`fill : equally`" then center every items inside three of the `UIView`s as center. + set additional constraints. You are Done. If you want UI guide comment here.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understood correctly, you are suggesting a stackview that contains my 3 other views? (The two stackviews and my "VS" view)
When I do that, and constraint the top stack view, i still get the result of my second screenshot. Any Ideas?

P.S.: I need the ImageView and the team label to be in a stack view since I will need to hide the imageViews sometimes and center the label

Comment: have you set UIStackView constraints with base cell view.

Comment: Actually this must be a visual bug in IB, when I kept the layout of my second screenshot when building on an actual device, the layout works as expected. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @LucasP. really. Good to hear! :) PS: If you have done. Plz close this question.